# Don't match whitespace at the end of line

Tags: notepad++, regex

When I use regular expression to replace white spaces, \s is also matching the end of a line and not just the space in a line. How do I rectify this to just replace the whitespaces in a line.

Comment: What regex syntax are you using? POSIX? POSIX Extended? Perl/PCRE? Python? JavaScript? Etc.

Comment: @grawity I am using notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` stands for any kind of white space, ie. simple space, tabulation, line break...

You can use `\h` for horizontal space: space or tabulation.

If you want to match only spaces between words, you can use: `(?<=\S)\h+(?=\S)`

where

- `(?<=\S)` is a positive lookbehind that make sure we have a non whitespace before
- `(?=\S)` is a positive lookahead that make sure we have a non whitespace after.

Answer (score 2):

You can match on the specific whitespace characters you want, rather than selecting all whitespace characters.

For example, to match one or more spaces and tabs, use `[ \t]+`. Note the space AND \t characters will be matched.

Comment: I believe that you did not get the question. I need to match the space between the words. Not match all the whitespaces.

Comment: You might be looking for `([ \t]+)(\S)`. That should let you find and replace using the replacement pattern `\t\2` and get tabs where you want